# How is procedural code converted into a circuit?

Tags: verilog, hdl

With non-procedural code, the digital circuit the code represents is relatively obvious.
However with procedural code, it's hard/impossible to see how it translates into a circuit.

The only method I know to convert a function into a circuit is to describe it in [canonical disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form). However doing this to implement even small amounts of procedural code would require a massive number of gates.

Comment: @Morgan I disagree. The question isn't about hardware; it's about the software-hardware interface from the perspective of software. Any answers to this problem would be algorithmic in nature. And even the hardware portion of the question can be abstracted to Boolean expressions; the question would then just be one of many that deals with the application of software to math.

And even if you want the question to be completely about software, you could interpret it as "How is Verilog procedural code converted into non-procedural code?", which would be identical for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @FarhadYusufali: Why do you say so? An `always_comb` is a procedural block and is often very representative of the circuit it is implementing.

Comment: I still think you would have gotten a better answer on electronics. Could you give some code examples of things that you think are easy to convert and things that are not. When writing verilog I always have a pretty good idea of how it can be realized in hardware, so some examples of what you have in mind would be useful.

Comment: Generally it's turned into a state machine. Also, the conversion tools often impose lots of restrictions on what can be transformed (such as banning recursion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually quite easy. First all loops are unrolled (the code is not synthesizable if they can't be unrolled) and all functions and tasks are inlined. After that you are only left with if- and case-statements and assignments (if- and case-statements are essentially the same). the if statements can be transformed into multiplexers with the conditions on the select inputs. For example

```
if (cond1) begin
   if (cond2)
      foobar <= expr1;
end else
   foobar <= expr2;
```

is the same as

```
foobar <= cond1 ? (cond2 ? expr1 : foobar) : expr2;
```

(notice how the old value of foobar is used in the cond1 && !cond2 case). Of course there are a couple of extra steps to handle blocking assignments, asynchronous resets, etc. But this is the basic idea.

I recommend using a synthesis tool on simple code snippets to learn more about the relationship between your code and the generated circuit. You can use of course whatever tool you are using already, but I can't write a response to your question without mentioning [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/), the Verilog synthesis tool I wrote. The command `yosys -p "proc;; show" test.v` will translate the module in test.v to a RTL netlist and display the circuit (needs graphviz and xdot installed). This will, for example, transform [this](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/files/counter.v) into [this](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/images/show_rtl.png).

Update: Farhad Yusufali asked in the comments about blocking assignments.

Consider the following code:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  a = x;
  if (b) begin
    c <= c + a;
    a = y;
  end
  d <= a;
  a = a + 1;
  e <= a;
end
```

now we can write this as two always blocks using only nonblocking assignment like this:

```
always @* begin
  a_1 <= x;
  if (b)
    a_2 <= y;
  else
    a_2 <= a_1;
  a_3 <= a_2 + 1;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (b)
    c <= c + a_1;
  d <= a_2;
  e <= a_3;
end
```

I.e. whenever `a` is used on the left side of an assignment, we move the assignment to the asynchronous block and change `a` to `a_<index>`. Whenever `a` is used on the right hand side we replace it with the last `a_<index>` we created. When we branch (such as in `if (b)`) and create a new `a_<index>` in one of the branches, then you have to make sure that the last assignment to a version of `a` in each branch goes to the same index, adding extra assignments as needed (such as the assignment of `a_2` in the else branch).

This notation of replacing a variable with multiple variables with indices in this way is a variation of what is known as [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) in the compiler design community.

Comment: Could you please expand on how a blocking assignment would be implemented?

Comment: @FarhadYusufali I've now added additional explanations for blocking assignments.

Answer (score 2):

> However doing this to implement even small amounts of procedural code
>   would require a massive number of gates.

That is exactly the point. Raising the abstraction level and using a tool to automatically synthesize a procedural block of code into a massive amount of gates is the productivity gain delivered by EDA tools. Synthesis coding guidelines are in place so that it can reduce a set of procedural assignments into canonical form.

Answer (score 0):

You would turn procedural code into a state machine that sequentially executes the steps of the procedure, in essence creating a regular CPU that has instructions specifically designed to run your program.

Optimizations are performed both on the procedural code to give a better conversion result and on the hardware abstraction model.

Answer (score 0):

A obvious way to implement procedural code as a circuit is to have the circuit be a processor that executes the procedural code.  In fact, this is done often, which is why there are so many microcontrollers out there.